# How can I use the OAuth2Decorator with Google Cloud Storage?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-api-python-client, google-cloud-storage

I am following this [instructions](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-python-client/wiki/OAuth2) in order to connect my app engine python web service with Google storage and specifically to be able to use files API. I went through the buzz example but doesn't seem to work for me. I need the web service to authorize in the background in order to be able to retrieve my files from storage.

I am trying to use the decorator in order to pass my client_id and client_secret but the process is not quite clear to me. Someone who can provide an example or elaborate a bit in the process?

edit: I am using python 2.7 runtime.

Comment: "It doesn't seem to work" is unhelpful. What did you try, and what happened?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to get it running properly by using the gslite.py script from the [au-to-do](http://code.google.com/p/au-to-do/) google appengine project with my credentials.

Answer (score 1):

This may not be the most direct answer, but have you explored the built in Google Storage API on App Engine?

http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/googlestorage/

This lets you bypass the native API all together.

Comment: Yes, and using App Identity you don't need to do OAuth.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using the apiclient along with the native REST API, it would look something like this...

```
from apiclient.discovery import build
import httplib2
from oauth2client.appengine import OAuth2Decorator

decorator = OAuth2Decorator(client_id=YOUR_GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
                            client_secret=YOUR_GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
                            scope=GOOGLE_SERVICE_SCOPE,
                            )

class MainHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):

   @decorator.oauth_required
   def get(self):
    service = build(SERVICE_NAME, 
                    SERVICE_VERSION,
                    http=decorator.http())
    magic = service.method()
```

It might help to look at some of the apiclient examples for other APIs. For example, there's a nice example of an App Engine integration with the Tasks API that also uses OAuth2.

http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/python/getting_started_with_tasks_api.html

Comment: But you can still retrieve the access token from the decorator, and use it with the REST API (See decorator.credentials.access_token and decorator.credentials.refresh_token).